# How do we track values of different registers while coding a large program

Tags: assembly, x86-16

here I represented an snap of msdos code, in this type of code block we often get a very disappointed situation, we can clearly see that at line number line number 26 we are storing value of DS:SI to ES:DI, but we can clearly see that register SI or it's content is no where near this line 26.
I very often encounter this type of situation while understanding assembly language coding.

```
    01 PUSH    CS
    02 POP     DS
    03 PUSH    CS
    04 POP     ES
    05 ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP,ES:DOSGROUP
    06 MOV     AX,OFFSET DOSGROUP:INITBLOCK
    07 ADD     AX,0Fh                  ; round to a paragraph
    08 MOV     CL,4
    09 SHR     AX,CL
    10 MOV     DI,DS
    11 ADD     DI,AX
    12 INC     DI
    13 MOV     [CurrentPDB],DI
    14 PUSH    BP
    15 PUSH    DX              ; Save COMMAND address
    16 MOV     AX,[ENDMEM]
    17 MOV     DX,DI

    18 invoke    SETMEM          ; Basic Header
    19 ASSUME  DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING
    20 PUSH    CS
    21 POP     DS
    23 ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP
    24 MOV     DI,PDB_JFN_Table
    25 XOR     AX,AX
    26 STOSW              ;<--------------------here
    27 STOSB
```

We can clearly see that value of SI is no where near the line number 26. What is the remedy of this type of problems. Are we make a hard copy of values of all registers that flow while coding the program or we go back in the code and find the value of SI (or any particular register) and then adjust it's value in our coding.

Comment: `STOSW` is not `MOVSW`. It does not use `DS:SI`. Read an instruction set reference. It only writes `AX` to `ES:DI`, both of which are set nearby. That said, in general, yeah you'd have to keep track of what is in the registers at all times.

Comment: There is a similar problem with the x87 co-processor, made more difficult by the register names, and the stack-like behaviour. The way to keep track is to make a chart, or make a comment of the arrangement each time it changes. In the x86 with practice you get used to it, just as a juggler knows which balls are in the air.

Comment: @Jester: There is some weirdness, though: this code sets `DS` and `DI` before `stos`, but it did `assume ES:NOTHING` after the last function call which I thought would make sense if it was clobbered by `SETMEM`.  So unless `ES` is still actually equal to `CS` from the push/pop at the top of this block, we don't know what `ES` is set to.  This might be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the title question: yes, use comments to describe which logical "variable" is going to be in which register for a block of code.  And document inputs/outputs/clobbers for each function.  Like `;;; input: ds:si pointer to a 0-terminated string` in some hypothetical function (not this one).  Within a function for temporaries, again comment at the place where you're calculating something.

If you're reading someone else's poorly documented code, you can *add* such comments at the top of a block, after looking through it to see if anything changes a certain register.  (That's non-trivial when there are function calls that you don't know which registers they clobber.  Using standard calling conventions makes that a lot easier, because you know which registers to assume are clobbered.)

---

As Jester points out, **this is `stos`, not `movs`, so it doesn't read `DS:SI`**.  It only stores AX and AL to `ES:DI` ([Intel docs](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/stos:stosb:stosw:stosd:stosq)).  However, this code looks broken: it sets `DS` but not `ES` right before that, as if it was expecting STOS to use `DS:DI` (which it doesn't).

Perhaps it works in practice because `SETMEM` didn't *actually* clobber `ES`, or set it to the value that this code wanted anyway.  But from the `assume ES:NOTHING` after the call to `SETMEM`, it looks like this code is expecting `SETMEM` to destroy `ES`.

I assume this code comes from DOS 1.0 that you've been looking at, so presumably `ES` is still actually equal to `CS` from the push/pop at the top of this block, by luck or something.

**This is a case where single-stepping it in a debugger might help to understand it.**  I think BOCHS's built-in debugger lets you set breakpoints anywhere, even in the OS's code, and they work even with interrupts disabled.

---

**Anyway, there's a limit to using comments when things get complex.**

That's why in real life we leave long-distance / large-scale optimization / constant-propagation to **compilers** (which are excellent at *that*), and mostly only worry about asm micro-optimizations for hot loops (where compilers aren't always great).